# Cross-lagged Pearson correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation, lag, pearson-correlation, pearson

I have a dataset where I have two recordings (sessions) of two different variables.

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.table(
    id = rep(1:20, each = 2),
    session = rep(1:2, times = 20),
    var1 = sample(1:100, size = 40, replace = TRUE,
    var2 = sample(5:10,  size = 40, replace = TRUE)
)
```

If I want to know the correlation between two variables at the same time point, I can simply calculate a Pearsons correlation:

```
#Cross-sectional Pearson correlation
data[session == 1, cor.test(var1, var2)]
```

However, if I want to know the correlation between var1 and var2 at different time points, should I use a cross-lagged Pearson correlation? And if so, how do I determine the lag?

I imagine it would look like so:

```
#Cross-lagged Pearson correlation
library(testcorr)
cc.test(data[session == 1, var1], data[session == 2, var1], max.lag = 1)
```

Since there are only two session, and the time lag between the two is 1 session, I imagine the lag should be defined as 1?

How about when I want to correlate the value of var1 at session 1 with the value of var2 at session 2? Do I use the same cross-lagged correlation?

```
cc.test(data[session == 1, var1], data[session == 2, var2], max.lag = 1)
```

Perhaps this question should fit  Cross Validated better, but ultimately I would like to get advice on how to code this using R. Thank you!

Comment: If you need help modeling your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. First find out the right thing to do with your data then google how to do that in R. And the folks at Cross Validated don't do all their statistics by hand; some use R as well.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will post my question there!